# Why is react-router changing the URL but not the page content?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I want the page to change when you click on one of the two boxes. The problem is that the URL changes as it is supposed to but page content remains and only changes after refreshing. I read some similar questions and tried adding withRouter and that produced the same results. Here's the code:

```
        import React from 'react';
        import './App.css';
        import NavBar from './Nav.js';
        import Library from './PathwayHome.js';
        import Profile from './ProfileHome.js';
        import Home from './HomePage.js';
        import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';



        function App () {
  
  
            return (
              <Router>
                <div className="Home">
                  <NavBar/>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/ProfileHome" exact component={Profile}/>
                    <Route path="/PathwayHome" exact component={Library}/>
                  </Switch>
                </div>
              </Router>
                );
        }



        export default App;



This is the component with the links:
```

```
    import React from 'react';
    import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
    import './App.css';
    import Footer from './FooterHome.js';
    import Profile from './ProfileHome.js';
    import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    import {Grid} from '@material-ui/core';




    function Home () {

        return (
            <Router>
            <Grid container spacing={12}>
             <div className="PaneContainer">
               <Link to="/ProfileHome"><div className="Profile"/></Link>
               <Link to="/PathwayHome"><div className="Pathway"/></Link>
             </div>
             <SearchBar/>
             <Footer/>
            </Grid>
            </Router>
            );
    }



    export default Home;
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm starting to wonder if maybe a multi-page webapp would be better for my use case and I should not use React? Thoughts/Suggestions?

Comment: I don't think your `Home` component needs to have any Routers in it at all. Try removing them.

Comment: That worked! Who knew it was something so simple. Thanks so much!